# Trying to load images from url into TextView

Tags: android, image, url

Trying to load images from url into TextView and everything goes fine except one thing. When I'm trying to return results from my ImageGetter it jumps into exception part of the code strait to return line skipping all code above and without any exceptions at all.

Here is the code.

```
package net.cosplace.tabun;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.text.Html;
import android.text.Html.ImageGetter;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.text.Spanned;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void TabunLogin(View v)
    {
        TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        AsyncTask<String, Void, Spanned> r = new RetreiveFeedTask().execute();

    }

class RetreiveFeedTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Spanned> {
        private Exception exception;

        protected Spanned doInBackground(String... urls) {
            try 
            {
                String inputLine = "";
                String buf = "";
                try
                {
                    URL yahoo = new URL("http://www.cosplace.net/photo.php");
                    URLConnection connection = yahoo.openConnection();
                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

                    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
                        buf += inputLine;

                    in.close();
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    buf = "fail";
                }

                ImageGetter imgGetter = new ImageGetter(){
                    @Override
                    public Drawable getDrawable(String source){
                           try
                           {
                                source = "http://www.cosplace.net/"+source;
                                URL url = new URL(source);

                                InputStream is = url.openStream();
                                Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
                                Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),b);
                                return d;
                           }
                           catch (Exception e)
                           {
                                System.out.println("Exc="+e);
                                return null;
                           }                    
                    }
                };
                Spanned s = Html.fromHtml(buf,imgGetter, null);

                return s;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                this.exception = e;
                return null;
            }

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Spanned result) {
            // TODO: check this.exception 
            // TODO: do something with the feed
            TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            txt.setText(result);
        }
    }
}
```

So when it goes to ImageGetter it successfully connects to url, retrieve data, creates bitmap and convert it to drawable, but then right before returning drawable it jumps to return null line of exception part without any exceptions at all. Just don't know whats the problem could be.

---

Manage to get it work. Just reorganized code near try and catch that it would be only one return derective in all method. And added setBounds.

```
            Drawable d = null;
               try
               {
                    source = "http://www.cosplace.net/"+source;
                    URL url = new URL(source);
                    InputStream is = url.openStream();
                    Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
                    d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),b);
                    d.setBounds(0,0,d.getIntrinsicWidth(),d.getIntrinsicHeight());
               }
               catch (Exception e)
               {
                    System.out.println("Exc="+e);
               }
               return d;
```

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: @sandrstar            `catch (Exception e)
            {
                this.exception = e;
                return null;
            }`
Here that nasty thing...

Comment: Mean, what exact exception have you observed? Have You observed logs?

Comment: @sandrstar that is the problem. There is nothing. Just weird behavior. Trying to reorganize code, maybe it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting file not found exception in **ImageGetter** `catch`

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://www.cosplace.net/http://itodama.net/images/banners/baner4.gif
```

visit the link generated from this line

```
source = "http://www.cosplace.net/"+source;
```

in browser . you will get this error in browser

```
Error 404. File not found
```

[image]

Comment: There is only couple links like that. Other links is valid and I checked them.